# Text aligns weirdly with justify-content: space-evenly;

Tags: css

So I have a list something like this:

```css
.ul-employee {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.li-employee {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul-employee">
  <li class="li-employee">
    <h3>Employee Name</h3>
    <p>Salary</p>
    <p>Position</p>
  </li>
  <li *ngFor="let employee of employees" class="li-employee">
    <h3>{{ employee.name }}</h3>
    <p>${{ employee.salary }} / hour</p>
    <p>{{ positions[employee.position] }}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmCeO.png)

The list is in a container with width of 400px, the list takes 100% of the width space and so does the list items. I tried doing text-align: left; but that doesn't seem to work.

How do I make it so it's aligned more like:
**Employee Name**   Salary   Position
**Employee Name**   Salary   Position
**Employee Name**   Salary   Position
**Employee Name**   Salary   Position
instead of one more to the right and another more to the left?

Comment: do you want it to space it evenly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2-dimension layout. Flex is for 1-Dimension layout.

You need `display: grid;`

Answer (score 0):

`display:table;` seems more appropriate than `display:flex` here if that's not a real table ... :

```css
.ul-employee {
  display: table; 
  text-align: left;
  height: 100%; 
}

.li-employee {
  display: table-row;
  width: 400px;
}
.li-employee > * {
display:table-cell;
border:solid;
padding:0.25em;
```

```html
<ul class="ul-employee">
  <li class="li-employee">
    <h3>Employee Name</h3>
    <p>Salary</p>
    <p>Position</p>
  </li>
  <li *ngFor="let employee of employees" class="li-employee">
    <h3>{{ employee.name }}</h3>
    <p>${{ employee.salary }} / hour</p>
    <p>{{ positions[employee.position] }}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```